# Building a Paging UserControl for ListView in Wpf

Tags: wpf, listview, user-controls, paging

I have a `ListView` in a WPF Window. This `ListView` is binded to a strongly typed list.
I have 10 Windows like this. each having a Listview binded to a strongly typed list.
I have a `StackPanel` with 4 buttons and a Label Below the `ListView` that serves as a Pager for the `ListView`. Currently, I am handling the Buttons events in the Code behind for the window.

Can anyone guide me on making this part of the pager a UserControl?
The part i am confused in is.. How do I handle the `List<type>` in the Code behind?

1) How do i Access the Usercontrol properties in the Codebehind for Window.
2) Where do i do the Actual Filtering for the list and Set the itemsource to the listview.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Button Name="btnFirst" Content="&lt;&lt;" Margin="2,2,15,2" Width="20"  Height="20" Tag="First"  ToolTip="First" Click="btnNav_Click"/>
        <Button Name="btnPrev" Content="&lt;" Margin="2,2,15,2" Width="20" Height="20" Tag="Prev" ToolTip="Previous" Click="btnNav_Click"/>
        <Label Name="lblPage" Margin="2,2,15,2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Name="btnNext" Content="&gt;" Margin="2,2,15,2" Width="20" Height="20" Tag="Next"  ToolTip="Next" Click="btnNav_Click"/>
        <Button Name="btnLast" Content="&gt;&gt;" Margin="2,2,0,2" Width="20" Height="20" Tag="Last"  ToolTip="Last" Click="btnNav_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thnkx Guys!.. But that is not what i was looking for !.. 
I have the paging imlementation with me .. but i want to make it generic and make a usercontrol that i could reuse in every wpf window.

Here's how i did it.

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Button Name="btnFirst" Content="&lt;&lt;" Margin="2,2,10,2" Width="20"  Height="20" Tag="First"  ToolTip="First" Click="btnNav_Click"/>
        <Button Name="btnPrev" Content="&lt;" Margin="2,2,10,2" Width="20" Height="20" Tag="Prev" ToolTip="Previous" Click="btnNav_Click"/>
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Page :" Margin="2,2,0,2"/>
        <ComboBox Name="cmbxPageNo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,2,4,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="35" Style="{StaticResource PagerCmbx}" SelectionChanged="cmbxPageNo_SelectionChanged" Height="18" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
        <Label Name="lblTotPage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Content="/ 5"/>
        <Button Name="btnNext" Content="&gt;" Margin="15,2,10,2" Width="20" Height="20" Tag="Next"  ToolTip="Next" Click="btnNav_Click"/>
        <Button Name="btnLast" Content="&gt;&gt;" Margin="2,2,0,2" Width="20" Height="20" Tag="Last"  ToolTip="Last" Click="btnNav_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

This is the ui for the control which would look like

now for the class..
http://pastebin.com/jGywtEgG

At the Xaml for the window . where u show the listview with the binded strongly typed list. 
Place the Usercontrol below the listview.

Set the itemsource for the listview={Binding ElementName = "nameof the usercontrol",Path = CurrentView}

CurrentView is the Property exposed in the class with Inotifypropertychanged implemented. 
That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good video tutorial by **Beth Massi** on `WindowsClient.net`. It covers paging along with many concepts useful for creating a Data-Centric application in `WPF`.

[How Do I: Create a Simple Data Entry Form in WPF](http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=41987)